# Leading "?" symbol in UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, html-parsing, jsoup

There is some file index.html (saved in UTF-8):

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
       <h1> THE TITLE </h1>     
       Please click <a href="url"> here </a>
       <br>  ... Some text... <br>    
       Image: <img  src="nature.png"/>    
       <br> ... Some another text... <br>    
        Image2: <img  src="nature2.png" />
   </body>
</html>
```

I need to fetch all the text containing inside the BODY tag, modify it, and save. So I do like this:

```
    File input = new File("html/input.html");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");     
    Elements body = doc.select("BODY");

    //do some manipulations with the data and print it
    System.out.println(body.html());
```

The result is:

```
?   
<h1> THE TITLE </h1> Please click 
<a href="url"> here </a> 
...
```

It's fine, except the question symbol at the begining. How can I avoid it? 
Of course I can just delete it from the result string) But I would like to understand whats the matter.

Comment: Is it possible that the `?` is really a UTF-8 BOM (byte order mark)?

Comment: Yes, you are right ). Hex editor tells it is really BOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to make a PrintStream that understands `UTF-8`:

```
 PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
 out.println(body.html());
```

Then try to redirect output to a file and see if there's still garbage when reading it as `UTF-8`.

If not then your console simply isn't `UTF-8` and doesn't know how to handle it.

Comment: If redirect to a file, then no any garbage. So problem with console. And, as as Keith Thompson noted, this symbol is acctually BOM. Thanks for help.

Comment: @user1117393 You should never ever ever use a BOM with UTF-8: that’s completely broken.  If you have a file with 10 different 50-character UTF-8 lines in it, you need to be able to run `cat file file file > triplicate` and get a proper 30-line file comprising exactly 1500 characters at the end.  Otherwise you’ve screwed up.